# How do I publish/export Microsoft Access Forms

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-access, vba, vbscript

I developed some forms in Microsoft Access and have yet to connect the forms with the database. However I would like to build and maybe publish the forms so I can view them outside of Access. how do I accomplish this please? If not possible, Is there a way to build and run access forms as you would your typical .NET windows forms?

Answer (score 2):

Access forms are totally different from .NET windows forms. .NET forms are first compiled to CIL languge, then at run-time, the CLR's JIT compiles it to native instructions just before the execution. This makes it possible to write once, and run on any computer where CLR is present.

This is not the case with access forms. They are totally "embedded" inside the Access .mdb/mda file, much like sheets and workbooks are "embedded" inside Excel file. So, the access form is totally dependent on the Access application to execute itself. So, no access=no access-form.

Answer (score 1):

One option for publishing is to use two database file. One contains your tables, and the other contains your forms. This way you can simply publish form changes by distributing a new version of the access file with the forms. You can also backup your code and data separately.

Another variation on this is to store your data in a relational database such as [Microsoft SQL Server Express](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Express) or MySQL(http://www.mysql.com/) and connect to the tables in Access as Linked Tables. Note that you will need an ODBC driver for the database you are storing the data in.